# How to write data to child node with AngularFire?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularfire

My rules are like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
  ".read": true,

  "simpleObject": {
    "$any": {
      ".write" : true
    }
  },
}
```

When I try to write data to "/simpleObject/field1" like this: (This way allow me to bind the entire "simpleObject" to my view using AngularJS, nice and simple :) )

HTML:

```
...
<pre>{{simpleObject | json}}</pre>
...
```

JS:

```
...
$scope.simpleObject = $firebaseObject(ref.child("simpleObject"));
$scope.simpleObject.field1 = "new value 1";
$scope.simpleObject.field2 = "new value 2";
$scope.simpleObject.$save();
...
```

It fails since simpleObject's writing rule is false

So I must use this instead:
HTML:

```
...
<pre>
{
  "field1": {{field1}},
  "field2": {{field2}}
}
</pre>
...
```

JS:

```
...
$scope.field1 = $firebaseObject(ref.child("simpleObject/field1"));
$scope.field1.$value = "new value 1";
$scope.field1.$save();
$scope.field2 = $firebaseObject(ref.child("simpleObject/field2"));
$scope.field2.$value = "new value 2";
$scope.field2.$save();
...
```

This way seems inconvenient because I have to create a new field in $scope and bind it to the view for every field in "simpleObject" and HTML code is more complex :(

How to write data to simpleObject's child node in the 1st method so that my HTML will stay simple and easy to understand?